# Enviar formulário via SOAP com PHP

Tags: php, formulário, soap

Olá, tudo bom?

Sou bem iniciante em PHP, e estou integrando o CRM de um cliente com um formulário para captação de Leads. O sistema deles tem uma abrangência pequena, e a única coisa que tenho para me auxiliar é um documento com algumas instruções - além de pesquisas aqui no SO e na internet.

No Google, encontrei algumas soluções para a validação, etapa necessária antes do envio do formulário. Testei e deu tudo certo - estou trabalhando com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx?WSDL');

$function = 'GetToken';

$arguments= array('GetToken' => array(
                  'ApiKey'   => XXXXXXXX
                ));

$options = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

$json = $result->GetTokenResult;
$item = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($item);

$apikey = 'XXXXXXXX';
$apipassword = 'YYYYYYYY';

$combinacao = $apikey."|".$apipassword."|".$item;

$combinacaomd5 = md5($combinacao);

$tokenfinal = $combinacaomd5."|".$apikey;

print_r($tokenfinal);

?>
```

Agora que tenho o token validado para envio do formulário, preciso entender como enviar os dados de um formulário no seguinte formato:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:PutLead>
            <tem:pessoa>
                <tem:Nome>Nome do lead</tem:Nome>
                <tem:Email>lead@email.com</tem:Email>
                <tem:Telefone>11 99999-9999</tem:Telefone>
                <tem:Observacoes>Observações do lead</tem:Observacoes>
            </tem:pessoa>
            <tem:Key>TOKEN GERADO PELO CÓDIGO ANTERIOR</tem:Key>
        </tem:PutLead>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Caso a requisição seja concluída com sucesso, deveremos ter o retorno do ID do lead - conforme código abaixo:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <PutLeadResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <PutLeadResult>ID DO LEAD</PutLeadResult>
        </PutLeadResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Pesquisei por diversas coisas, mas não encontrei nada relevante sobre o assunto - não sei nem se é a melhor forma de realizar este processo. Preferi seguir com o PHP pois tenho alguma afinidade. Alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Luz => [PHP:SOAP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.soap.php)

Answer (score -1):

Dei uma lida no material divido pelo Augusto, e algumas coisas que eu encontrei na internet - cheguei no seguinte:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];


$client = new SoapClient('http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx?WSDL');

$function = 'GetToken';

$arguments= array('GetToken' => array(
                                        'ApiKey'   => XXXXXXXXXXX
                                      )
                 );

$options = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

$json = $result->GetTokenResult;
$item = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($item);

$apikey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$apipassword = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$combinacao = $apikey."|".$apipassword."|".$item;

$combinacaomd5 = md5($combinacao);

$tokenfinal = $combinacaomd5."|".$apikey;

print_r($tokenfinal);

$argumentsPost = array('PutLead' => array(
                            'Pessoa'   => array(
                                    'Nome'   => $nome,
                                    'Email'   => $email,
                                    'Telefone'   => $telefone,
                                    'Observacoes'   => $observacoes
                            ),
                            'Key' => array(
                                'ApiKey'   => $tokenfinal
                              )
                            )
                        );

$optionsPost = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

$functionPost = 'PutLead';

$resultPost = $client->__soapCall($functionPost, $argumentsPost, $optionsPost);

?>
```

Código do formulário:

```
<form id="formulario" action="https://superaguaruja.com.br/crm4u/apiguaruja.php" method="post">
<div width="100%">
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="campos" placeholder="Seu nome" required>
</div>
<div width="100%">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="campos" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required>
<div width="100%">
    <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone" class="campos" placeholder="Seu celular" required>
</div>    
<div width="100%" class="motivo">
    <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Selecionar">----- Com o que podemos te ajudar?</option>
    <option value="Concurso e vestibular">Concurso e vestibular</option>
    <option value="Inteligência">Inteligência</option>
    <option value="Memória">Memória</option>
    <option value="Profissional">Profissional</option>
    <option value="Alzheimer">Alzheimer</option>
    <option value="Ansiedade">Ansiedade</option>
    <option value="Atenção">Atenção</option>
    <option value="Estresse">Estresse</option>
    <option value="Estudo">Estudo</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div width="100%" align="center">
    <button id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" class="btn-enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Quando eu envio, aparece o seguinte erro:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Index was outside the bounds of the array. in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php(58): SoapClient->__soapCall('PutLead', Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php on line 58

É algum erro na forma com que eu coloquei os arrays, ou na última string? Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado!